# Can view apn but cannot change it

Tags: cellular-data, iphone, apns

I've been using my iphone 5C with operator Mobile Vikings (prepaid) without a problem in Belgium. I bought a europe roaming pack and was hoping to use this in Croatia. 
But after arriving in Croatia, my APN settings changed and I'm unable to modify them... I can find them, view them, but when i modify them the changes are not saved... Am I doing something wrong?
What's going on? How can I correct this to use mobile internet again?

The phone is unlocked, using iOS 8.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution. I Installed the right APN settings via http://www.unlockit.co.nz

Then I disabled the "EU internet" setting.

*update: I guess the "EU internet" enabled setting is the reason who I couldn't change the APN settings.*..

Comment: I will note that I bought this Iphone outside of Europe (not sure if that makes any difference)...